# Website localization

Tags: php, javascript, localization, geolocation, translation

I would like to ask about best practices or the simplest way possible of translating static content. E.g. translating, "search" or "save changes".

My current idea is:

depending on users browser locale (maybe geolocation of IP address, but I prefer browser locale) choose a subdomain, e.g. "fr.myweb.com". Set a cookie, session variable, depending on settings with the language. This part is fairly straightforward.

Now comes the translating part. Changing images depending on language wont be a problem, since a "_fr" prefix is enough. But translating strings like save changes, search, order items, etc. . Well, I am not sure here.

Since its all based on PHP and MySQL, I was thinking of something like:

Two tables:

1. First one has list of all words in default language
2. Second one has three columns (excluding auto increment) - language_id, translation, word_id

Get all words, cache the query or whatever and now calling trans('fr', 'search') would translate the word. This should work, although I dont know if its the right approach or if there is a better way. Note: No google translations.

Also since I use js/ajax, I am not sure about this part either. Get the language from cookie and do a map of alerts, etc. and then just call "message['fr']", I am not sure about this part either.

Any ideas what would be ideal for both languages? I tried google, but wasnt satisfied with the results. Any advice/link is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Avoid the database for storing translating strings. Use either gettext .po files or a php arrays. Avoid difficult APIs. Use something like `_("english")` or `__("..")` and carry around the target language elsewhise. Don't use constants or text IDs, use raw english as input. -- Explain why you seemingly want to do translations client-side (AJAX?) and not at page generation (PHP).

Comment: I didnt mean ajax, but JS. Lets say you have to meet certain conditions to do an action, if you dont meet them - you get a JS error. What about translating those?

Comment: Still don't know the exact situation, but you might try this http://plugins.jquery.com/project/gettext

Comment: @mario why should we avoid database? I think it doesn't require to restart apache each time chaging the .po file like in gettext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up Gettext for PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php. It's the de facto standard for providing web content translations. Basically you build translation files (you can use for example [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)), point PHP to them, set the locale to whatever is needed and use `_( 'string to translate' )` to fetch the translations.